# how can I scroll the view automatically on changing slider value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scrollbar, slider

I want to control scroll bar by slider so when user slides the slider scroll bar should also scroll the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your slider is declared as 'slider' and the scroll view is declared as 'scrollView':

```
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Now create a method `- (void)sliderChanged:(id)sender`. It should get the slider's value with `slider.value`, determine where to scroll your scroll view (a `CGRect` that should be visible) to and then `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:animated:]`

Comment: what value should be passed for CGRect as I tried using this code but no scroll is happening on changing slider

Comment: @Spikydude: You can you **setContentOffset** method instead. Try the following Code. I didn't test it. `CGSize scrollViewSize = scrollView.contentSize;
float scroll_to_y = scrollViewSize.height * (slider.value / 100);
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.x, scroll_to_y) animated:YES];`

Comment: @Spikydude First of all, confirm that the method gets called by placing an NSLog statement in it. For CGRect you pass a structure made by CGRectMake(x,y,width,height). So to scroll by 200 points from the top of the scroll view you would pass in CGRectMake(0,200,1,1)

Comment: @Simon thanks. Now how can i change slider value on scrolling manually
i.e opposite to above

Comment: @Spikydude: Check if the following works. `sliderValue = (scollView.contentOffset.y / scollView.contentSize.height) * 100;`

Comment: @Spikydude: Then, `[slider setValue:sliderValue animated:YES]`

Comment: @Simon where should i write this line, is there any scroll bar function in which i can write this line

Comment: @Spikydude: Yes. In `scrollViewDidScroll` method of `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: @Simon ya its working but scrolling is not smooth it bounces back to original place on small scroll made on it but if we make large scroll it changes.(I am talking regarding scroll bar not slider, slider is working fine)

Comment: @Spikydude: I guess you need to make some minor changes.